# How to use TouchableOpacity onPress in side menu?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How to implement active links to other pages in side menu?
 I'm using this example https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-side-menu/tree/master/examples/Basic on my app, but when I added `TouchableOpacity` with `onPress` function

```
this.props.navigator.push({
        name: 'Main'
    });
```

I had an error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". And all functions execute when side menu opened (before I press the buttons). How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had an error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

You need to use

```
<Menu navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
```

instead of

```
<Menu/>
```